# esbuild fails without parcel installed

Tags: esbuild

A project that uses esbuild fails as follows ...

```
node_modules/htmlparser2/lib/Parser.js:133:36: error: Could not resolve "events" (set platform to "node" when building for node)
require("inherits")(Parser, require("events").EventEmitter);
                                    ~~~~~~~~
1 error
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
node_modules/htmlparser2/lib/Parser.js:133:36: error: Could not resolve "events" (set platform to "node" when building for node)
    at failureErrorWithLog (/Volumes/DUMBLEDORE1/Users/fficnar/Projects/Shared Projects/mablung-virtual-pug/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:640:15)
    at /Volumes/DUMBLEDORE1/Users/fficnar/Projects/Shared Projects/mablung-virtual-pug/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:504:31
    at handleIncomingPacket (/Volumes/DUMBLEDORE1/Users/fficnar/Projects/Shared Projects/mablung-virtual-pug/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:486:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (/Volumes/DUMBLEDORE1/Users/fficnar/Projects/Shared Projects/mablung-virtual-pug/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:429:7)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:303:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:279:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:218:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
  errors: [
    {
      location: [Object],
      text: 'Could not resolve "events" (set platform to "node" when building for node)'
    }
  ],
  warnings: []
}
```

... but if parcel is installed ...

```
npm install --save-dev parcel-bundler
```

... it succeeds.

The test is ...

```
import '@virtualpatterns/mablung-source-map-support/install'
import _Bundler from 'esbuild'
import Path from 'path'

const { 'build': Bundle } = _Bundler
const FilePath = __filePath
const Require = __require

async function main() {

  try {

    await Bundle({
      'entryPoints': [ Require.resolve('../library/utility.js') ],
      'outfile': `process/esbuild${Path.extname(FilePath)}`,
      'minify': false,
      'bundle': true
    })
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }

}

main()
```

... but I've also tried running the following from the command-line with the same error (sans stack trace) ...

```
esbuild distributable-esmodule/library/utility.js --bundle --outdir=process/esbuild --sourcemap --platform=browser --log-level=info --strict
node_modules/htmlparser2/lib/Parser.js:133:36: error: Could not resolve "events" (set platform to "node" when building for node)
require("inherits")(Parser, require("events").EventEmitter);
                                    ~~~~~~~~
1 error
```

The offending `require("events")` is coming from `html-to-vdom`.  My utility.js is small and contains the following import's ...

```
import _ConvertToVirtualNode from 'html-to-vdom'
import CreateVirtualNode from 'virtual-dom/h.js'
import VirtualNode from 'virtual-dom/vnode/vnode.js'
import VirtualText from 'virtual-dom/vnode/vtext.js'
```

I'm using esbuild v0.7.19.  Help.  What else should I provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the error message says `set platform to "node" when building for node`, I assume that since you didn't do that this means you are bundling for the browser, not for node. The `events` package is built in to node but it is not built in to the browser.

It looks like `parcel-bundler` depends on `node-libs-browser` which depends on `crypto-browserify` which depends on `events`. This explains why installing Parcel fixes this error. If your project needs to depend on the `events` package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/events), you should install it yourself so it's part of your project:

```
npm install events
```

Comment: I installed the `events` and `buffer` packages listed by the `node-libs-browser` package at [node-libs-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-libs-browser).  This eliminated the errors.  Thanks 